# Create an Oracle SQL user defined report table

Tags: plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have 3 tables where `REPORTTBL1`, `OFFICES` and `LANGUAGES`, and their relationships are shown in the graph below. [image: relationships]. Now I want to create a table (or a stored procedure) where the X-axis is `OFFICES.OFFICE_ID` and y-axis is `LANGUAGES.LANGUAGE_ID`, and every cell represents a how many times a language is used in the particular office (e.g. amount of times Chinese is used in the Moscow office, or better described below).

[image]

And I only want the data from a certain timeframe. The procedure I wrote is

```
    create procedure procedure1 (
cursor_ out sys_refcursor)as
    begin
open cursor_ for
    SELECT 
            lng.language "Language", 
            sum(decode( off.office_id, 1, 1, 0)) Moscow, 
            sum(decode( off.office_ID, 2, 1, 0)) "New York", 
            sum(decode( off.office_ID, 3, 1, 0)) "Tel Aviv",    
            sum(decode( off.office_ID, 1, 1, 0) 
            + decode( off.office_ID, 2, 1, 0) 
            + decode( off.office_ID, 3, 1, 0) 
            ) Total 
        FROM Offices off, Languages lng, reporttbl1 rep 
        WHERE off.Office_ID = rep.Office_ID (+) AND rep.language_id = lng.language_id --(+) AND rep.language_id !=0 and rep.language_id is not null 
        AND rep.ticket_date BETWEEN '5-DEC-2015' AND '5-JAN-2015' 
        GROUP BY LNG.LANGUAGE 
        ORDER BY lng.language;
    end;
```

But it doesn't seem to work. It does not select and display the correct data I want in the image above. Can someone please let me know how to do this? I prefer Oracle SQL but SQL Server also works. Please let me know if you need more info.

Comment: you dont really need to make a stored procedure or use pl/sql.I think, you can achieve this with just a simple select query.and Please add more details about the tables and expected results.(sorry cant see the image)

Comment: A stored procedure in Oracle can't just contain a `SELECT` statement.  Do you want to have a stored procedure that has an `OUT` parameter of type `sys_refcursor`?  Or a stored function that returns a `sys_refcursor`?  Or you could have a pipelined table function if you want to create an object type.  You could create a table and insert the data into the table in a stored procedure.  But the data in the table will be immediately out of date when someone changes data in the base tables.

Comment: @brenners1302 the relatioships are [here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/jkhgZ.png) and I expected the report to be like [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Ij1a8.png). I do not need a stored procedure but I want to reuse the SQL for reports somewhere else, like in Visual Studio or embed it on a website, etc. Can you provide your simple select query if you have a chance please?

Answer (score 1):

You can run the query with out stored procedure. However, your date comparison can cause the issues, you need to apply to_date function like this `rep.ticket_date BETWEEN to_date('05-DEC-2015', 'DD-MON-YYYY') AND to_date('05-JAN-2015', 'DD-MON-YYYY')`, unless rep.ticket_date is of type char/varchar.

Comment: Thanks. That is a healthy suggestion, however it doesn't solve my problem. My date range works just fine. The problem is, some data are not being selected in my report.

Comment: Problem is your date range is comparing data as strings

Comment: Thanks. I changed my SQL, but the report data is still incomplete. Plus, I used the same time format in another procedure and it worked just fine.